# Elasticsearch won't start, asking for certificates on npm

Tags: git, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to write a custom plugin for kibana following this tutorial/blog.
https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/
I'm stuck at the npm run elasticsearch step in my git-bash with the following output/error on my screen, how do I fix this? 
P.S. I am new to ELK

Here is the error I get...

> $ npm run elasticsearch
>
> > kibana@5.0.0-alpha6 elasticsearch C:\Users\sganti\kibana
> >     grunt esvm:dev:keepalive
>
> Running "esvm:dev:keepalive" (esvm) task starting up "dev" cluster
>   Keeping elasticsearch alive, to shutdown press command/control+c INFO
>   -  - cluster - Downloading & installing from "master" branch. Fatal error: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run"
>   "elasticsearch" npm ERR! node v4.4.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! kibana@5.0.0-alpha6 elasticsearch: `grunt
>   esvm:dev:keepalive` npm ERR! Exit status 3 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at
>   the kibana@5.0.0-alpha6 elasticsearch script 'grunt
>   esvm:dev:keepalive'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the
>   kibana package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author
>   that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     grunt esvm:dev:keepalive
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs kibana npm ERR! Or if that isn't
>   available, you can get their info via: npm ERR! npm ERR!     npm owner
>   ls kibana npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\sganti\kibana\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Kibana and elasticsearch have the same version. After downloading the kibana master you can change it to any version you want by:
**git checkout v5.4.0**  (replace the version with the one you want & you have to be inside the kibana directory)
In your custom plugin folder, in the **package.json** include  version as:

**"version": "5.4.0"** or whatever kibana version plugin you are developing.

Try running elasticsearch now.